# Converting innerText to innerHTML after some changes to text

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm going through my innerHTML to find the index of a certain string so I can add style tags to it and highlight it - To do it, I use something like:

```
i = htmlText.indexOf(lcSearchTerm, i+1);
```

The problem is that, if my lcSearchTerm is:

```
"Find word"
```

But if in the innerHTML it's as:

```
"<span> Find </span> word"
```

I won't find the index of the string, since it won't find the string we're looking for).

So my idea was to find it in the innerText inside and highlighting it there.
The problem is that afterwards, I need to convert it back to innerHTML to update the page with the changes. I should be something like:

```
innerText = "Find word"
innerText = Stylize(innerText)
innerText = "<font style='color:blue; background-color:yellow;'> Find word </font>"

innerHTML = TextToHTML(innerText);
innerHTML = "<body> 
                 <div> 
                     <font style='color:blue; background-color:yellow;'> Find word </font> 
                 </div> 
             </body>"
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to strip the tags by creating a function:

```
function strip_html_tags(str) {
  if ((str === null) || (str === '')) {
    return '';
  }

  return str.toString().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}

i = strip_html_tags(htmlText).indexOf(lcSearchTerm, i+1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused. Isn't that removing the tags on the searchTerm? The searchTerm never had any tags to begin with

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be the ```htmlText``` that needs to be passed to the ```strip_html_tags``` function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are highlighting words in an element with id `container`

```
const el = document.getElementById('container');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/searchterm/g,(w) => `<font>${w}</font>`)
```